# How to apply rotation about X and Z in stim?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit, stim

I have a quantum circuit illustrated in the provided image, where I perform a series of quantum operations followed by a projective measurement.[image].

Using Qiskit, I've already written the code for this circuit. Now, I'm interested in **using the ***[stim](https://pypi.org/project/stim/)*** library to obtain the final state after the measurement. How can I accomplish this?**

Qiskit code is

```python
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, Aer, assemble

qubits = 4
qc = QuantumCircuit(qubits,1)

hx = 1
hz = 1

qc.rx(2*hx,np.arange(qubits))
qc.rz(2*hz,np.arange(qubits))

#even evolution
qc.cx(np.arange(0,qubits-1,2),np.arange(1,qubits,2))
qc.rz(2,np.arange(1,qubits,2))
qc.cx(np.arange(0,qubits-1,2),np.arange(1,qubits,2))
#odd evolution
qc.cx(np.arange(1,qubits-1,2),np.arange(2,qubits,2))
qc.rz(2,np.arange(2,qubits,2))
qc.cx(np.arange(1,qubits-1,2),np.arange(2,qubits,2))

qc.measure(2, 0)
# Transpile the circuit for simulation
simulator = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')
compiled_circuit = transpile(qc, simulator)

# Simulate the circuit and get the final state vector
result = simulator.run(compiled_circuit).result()
final_state_vector = result.get_statevector()

# Print the final state vector
print(final_state_vector)
```

Answer (score 3):

See [Gates supported by Stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/gates.md) in stim's doc/ directory.

Stim only supports stabilizer gates, so it can't rotate by 2 radians around the Z axis like you are doing in your circuit. The closest would be the `SQRT_Z` gate, which rotates by $\pi/2$ radians around Z.

In a stabilizer circuit you can only do rotations that would leave a cube looking identical before and after the rotation. You can rotate by multiples of 90 degrees around the X, Y, or Z axis (e.g. gates like `SQRT_X`). You can rotate 180 degrees around the sum of two axes, like X+Z (gates like `H`). Or you can rotate 120 degrees around the sum of three axes, like X+Y+Z (gates like `C_XYZ`). And that's it.